# Passing values via ajax to second jsp page after Success response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am trying to send an ajax request to a java file from page1.jsp. Based on the response I would redirect to a jsp page. that is : If the response is "success" I would like to redirect to CreateBluemixMonkey.jsp page along with the parameter "data". Is that possible via the below code. As per my understanding since the "POST" method is redirected to a java class,once the control is  returned , variables from page1.jsp wouldnt be recognised in CreateBluemixMonkey.jsp. Please find the code in page1.jsp below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var userInfo = ['username','password' ];

for (var i=0; i < userInfo.length; i++) {   
var ele = userInfo[i];
values[ele] = $('#' + ele).val();
datas = datas + '"'+ ele + '"' + ': ' + '"' + values[ele] + '"' +',';
}
datas = datas + "}";


 $('#submit-button').click(function(){

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "./api/v2/chaos",
    data: datas,
    success: function(msg){
                       var successUrl = "CreateBluemixMonkey.jsp"; 
                       window.location.href = successUrl;

                },
                error: function(jqXHR,error, errorThrown) {
                $('#output').html(  jqXHR.status+ "  "         +jqXHR.responseText);

                }


    }) //ajax-close

  }) //click-function

 }) //document-ready
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try passing data using URL but this technique is good if data is short
>   . ELse you will get max query length error.

```
window.location = '/player_detail?data=' + data;
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to access the value of "data" in the jsp page

Answer (score 1):

Once the `window.location.href = successUrl;` is executed,the jsp page would get redirected to `CreateBluemixMonkey.jsp` with new request and response objects. Thus all data will be garbage collected. You can try storing data in `session` as because `session` can be made available to all pages.

You can read about it at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_session_tracking.htm

Answer (score 1):

The 6 lines that generate `datas` are pretty dodgy:

- `values` isn't declared, and if this doesn't fail on `values[ele]` it's only because the global scope contains an object `values` which you're mutating.
- Once you fix this, `datas` will look like this: `"username": "ambikanair","password": "wnt#*@$",}`. You're missing the opening `{`, and you've got a trailing `,`. If the server is expecting valid JSON it will be disappointed.
- You also haven't escaped the data. You should get into the habit of doing this properly, because there are plenty of situations where failure to escape things can be a security hole. In this case security isn't a problem, since a malicious user could post anything they wanted anyway, so you shouldn't be relying on them not posting invalid JSON etc.* But apart from malicious attacks, there's also the possibility of strings with strange characters messing it up by accident. Bear in mind that the password field is likely to contain non-alphanumeric characters. For example, if the password is `my"password` or `mypassword\`, `datas` will not be valid JSON.

Escaping strings can be tricky, but you don't normally have to do it yourself. In this case you should use the function `JSON.stringify`, which is part of the javascript language. I'd rewrite those lines as follows:

```
var values = {};
for (var i=0; i < userInfo.length; i++) {   
    var ele = userInfo[i];
    values[ele] = $('#' + ele).val();
}
var datas = JSON.stringify(values);
```

* As an example of what could be done if this was an issue, imagine the user enters the password `my password", "anotherfield": {"success": true, "data": "ncosneconoabneonvosief"}, "yetanotherfield": "yetanothervalue`. You'd end up with a perfectly valid JSON string containing fields that weren't meant to be there, and yet the user did this just by entering data under username and password.

Comment: Thanks for the valid suggestions. It really helped to improve my code :) :)